# Jooq doesn't use default value with store function

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I try to store an attempt object with the following constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE ATTEMPT ADD COLUMN files json NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::json;
```

and the code:

```
AttemptRecord attemptRecord = context.newRecord(T_ATTEMPT, attempt);
setAttemptId(attempt.getId());
store();
```

but when I store it with Jooq I have the following error:

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "files" violates the not-null constraint
```

Before this instead of the json files column I had a bytearray column, I everything worked well with the default value.
I also use the debugger tool and the AttemptRecord contains this value for files, it's sound weird to me but I don't know what does it mean.

```
{NullNode@3189} "null"
```

It's not really null like if JsonNode was null.

Why Jooq ignore the default value?

Answer (score 3):

#### Explanation:

The problem is with your calling

```
AttemptRecord attemptRecord = context.newRecord(T_ATTEMPT, attempt);
```

[Consider the Javadoc](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord-org.jooq.Table-java.lang.Object-):

> The resulting record will have its internal "changed" flags set to true for all values.

Your `attempt` POJO has no way of distinguishing between

- a `null` value with the semantics of SQL `DEFAULT`
- a `null` value with the semantics of SQL `NULL`

Because of this, the fact that you're actively setting the value of the `files` column by passing the POJO (which in turn calls the record setter for each column), the most reasonable default behaviour is to set the `changed()` flag to `true` for that column, and thus assume you want to send a `null` value to the database.

If this weren't the case, there would be quite a few SQL features that could not be used effectively, including e.g. some triggers that trigger only on certain columns being inserted/updated.

I've also recently documented this in a blog post: https://blog.jooq.org/2018/11/05/how-to-use-jooqs-updatablerecord-for-crud-to-apply-a-delta/

#### Workaround: Fix this for a single case:

The workaround in this case could be to reset the `changed()` flag for the `files` column using :

```
attemptRecord.changed(ATTEMPT.FILES, false);
```

#### Workaround: Fix this for all `store()` method calls

A more thorough fix could be to implement a [`RecordListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RecordListener.html), which fires every time before you run `store()`, or `insert()`, or `update()` calls, allowing you to patch the record being stored.

More information here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/crud-record-listener

Comment: thank for it, I understand better now, so I guess it's better to use https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#executeInsert-R- in my case ?

Comment: @Limmy: That doesn't change anything, it will still simply insert all the "changed" values